# Local function not polymorphic

Tags: ocaml

```
utop # let f : 'a -> 'a  = fun x -> x in (f 0, f true);;
Error: This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type int
```

"This expression" refers to the `true` in `f true`.

Why does the above fail, but the below succeed?

```
utop # let f : 'a -> 'a  = fun x -> x;;
val f : 'a -> 'a = <fun>

utop # (f 0, f true);;
- : int * bool = (0, true)
```

Comment: I believe this has something to do with unification variables being scoped to the outer function.

Comment: From [the manual](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/types.html#sss:typexpr-variables): "In general the scope of a named type variable is the whole top-level phrase where it appears, and it can only be generalized when leaving this scope. Anonymous variables have no such restriction. "

Comment: I'm sure there's an interesting reason for this that someone more familiar with the compiler internals can elaborate on.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I don't think the value restriction is relevant here so I think marking this as a duplicate question is incorrect.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I don't think this is the value restriction, since this restriction only applies to named type variables, not anonymous ones. And in this case it's also a syntactic function, so you'd think the relaxed value restriction would allow it anyway.

Comment: BTW to fix this, all you need to do is replace unification variables with universal variables: `let f : 'a. 'a -> 'a = ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by glennsl in comments, per [the manual](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/types.html#sss:typexpr-variables) the type variables (e.g. `'a`) are defined for the entire toplevel definition where they occur.

> In general the scope of a named type variable is the whole top-level phrase where it appears

Consider defining a simple function `f` with a locally scoped function `g` which specifies a type of `'a -> 'a`:

```
# let f x y =
    let g (x : 'a) : 'a = x in
    (g x, g y);;
val f : 'a -> 'a -> 'a * 'a = <fun>
```

Because `'a` is scoped to the definition of `f` it has to be unified accordingly. The only way this can work is if `x` and `y` have the *same* type.

There is no such restriction if we elide the explicit type annotation on `g`.

```
# let f x y =
    let g x = x in
    (g x, g y);;
val f : 'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b = <fun>
```

Another example. Starting *without* explicit type annotations. The compiler correctly infers that all four arguments must have wildcard types. It uses `'a` through `'d'`.

```
# let f a b c d =
    let g x y = (x, y) in
    let h x y = (x, y) in
    (g a b, h c d);;
val f : 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> ('a * 'b) * ('c * 'd) = <fun>
```

And adding the explicit type annotation, the compiler infers that all four arguments must have wildcard types, but because we have already via passing them as arguments to `g` and `h` given those types names, `a` and `c` mst both save the same type, as must `b` and `d`.

```
# let f a b c d =
    let g (x : 'a) (y : 'b) : ('a * 'b) = (x, y) in
    let h (x : 'a) (y : 'b) : ('a * 'b) = (x, y) in
    (g a b, h c d);;
val f : 'a -> 'b -> 'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b) * ('a * 'b) = <fun>
```